# How to get a url from a pin that can be opened on a webview

Tags: android, api, pinterest

I am using the Pinterest Android SDK to authenticate and read pins from Boards I follow. 
The issue is in my app, I need to to open the URL of the pin in a webview to able to read the pin contents in my app itself without leaving my app. 
Currently, I can use the "url" field from the getPin() API response json, but the URL redirects from the webview to the pinterest app (leaving my app).
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you intend to show the entire pin or just the image? If you use the URL of the getPin() API then it is the URL to a "Pin" which is a Pinterest object and will always have a "Pinterest.com". Hence it will redirect itself to Pinterest app, which is the correct behaviour.

However, you can get the URL of the image from the Pin that you retrieved using getPin and display that within the app.

The other problem with your approach is that it tries to replicate the behaviour of Pinterest itself which is in violation of Pinterest policies and they may ban your app. So my suggestion would be to use the URL of the image of the pin and display inside an imageview of your app using Picasso or Glide.

All the best...